# Xamarin System.InvalidCastException: Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' to type 'Android.Widget.Button'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This error didn't appear until I added

```
private void ExList_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ExList.RemoveViewAt(e.Position);
        Openers.Remove(e.Position.ToString());
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The full code just takes input text from the Itext textview  and adds it to Openers which goes to the ExList Listview. The adapter is a simple one. 
Itext.text = ""; highlights with the debugger, So I assume it stops at that line. 
heres the code.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        public List<string> Openers = new List<string>();

        Button AButton;
        TextView Itext;
        ListView ExList;
        Button SettingsB;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        public OpenersView adap;//Custom adapter class


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);



            SettingsB = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SettingsB);
            AButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddB);
            Itext = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Itext);
            ExList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ExList);

            //adap = new OpenersView(this, Openers); //Custom adapter
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Openers);//Simple adapter
            ExList.Adapter = adapter;


            AButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {

                if (Itext.Text.Length > 8) { Openers.Add(Itext.Text); }
                adap.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                Itext.Text = "";
                //I declare the listview here so it will update every click of the button.
            };

            ExList.ItemClick += ExList_ItemClick;



        }

        private void ExList_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ExList.RemoveViewAt(e.Position);
            Openers.Remove(e.Position.ToString());
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your `Main.axml` file ??

Comment: Yeah. The problem seem to be in your designer.  You might have had an Edit text and in your main code you are trying to convert it to a button.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Button in xml code.
make sure that Resource.Id.SettingsB and Resource.Id.AddB are buttons.

if its editText change like this

```
        SettingsB = FindViewById< Edittext >(Resource.Id.SettingsB);   //check xml
        AButton = FindViewById< Edittext >(Resource.Id.AddB);         //check xml
```